# SQL: SQL query to compare two schema and update the old schema with the new columns of new schema

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the MS SQL database and stuck in the scenario. I want to compare two schemas and update the existing table with the new/missing columns of new schema. So i am looking for a SQL query which will compare the existing table schema with the new schema and alter table according to the new schema.

For example, I am having existing 'customer' table and having new schema(customer table schema with additional column) of the same table and new schema contains some new column or missing column so want to alter the customer table as per the new schema

Please, let me know if any other information required.

Comment: Are you familiar with Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes.. I am .net developer.

Comment: If you want to achieve this with SQL only then try below query. Otherwise there is an option in VS to compare schema with two database wit Database project

Comment: My suggestion is Adept Sql Open source tool for Comparing 2 databases and generates script.

Comment: I do not want to do it manually. My script will execute at run time automatically. So i need sql script for the same.